# Help with collision equation

Tags: c++, math

I made collision equation
(col and cold are lines ->x and ->y are start points and h() and w() are height and width). o & z are unknown.

```
    col->x+(col->w())*o=cold->x+(cold->w())*z;
     col->y+(col->h())*o=cold->y+(cold->h())*z;
```

and I solved it:

```
z=(cold->y-col->y-col->h()/col->w()* (cold->x-col->x))/(col->h()/col->w()*cold->w() - cold->h());
o=(cold->x+cold->w()*z-col->x)/col->w();
```

It works well(? not sure),  but if one of lines is vertical or horizontal I get everywhere NaNs. Somebody got idea why? Is it correct (I did it six times)?

Comment: It's not clear what your code is doing here.  Are you talking about calculating the intersection of two lines?

Comment: If you're looking for the intersection of two lines check this out: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/

Answer (score 4):

You're probably dividing zero by zero in those cases.

I'd suggest breaking your assignment down into step-by-step pieces, and checking the value as you go.

Comment: It would have to be 0/0.  x/0 gives +/-inf for x!=0.

Comment: In hindsight, this is probably more of a comment than the answer I'd intended it to be. Still, it's the solution to debugging the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing it wrong. It's kind of hard to tell, though, because you apparently can't be bothered to tell us what on earth you're trying to do. Oh, and if you're doing it wrong, it's still wrong if you've been doing it wrong six times. I found that doing it right once is by far the superior approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) (I'm lazy) I get:

[image]

This should give you a division by zero if coldw colh = coldh colw, or coldh/coldw = colh/colw, i.e. when both slopes are equal (in other words, when both lines are parallel).